# if else statements in mysql where clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get user details and profile image from 2 tables using joins. The issue is that not all users have a prof image therefore i have to use an if condition in the where clause. Users without prof pic have default 0 as their prof pic image 0 does not belong to anyone the rest have their prof pic id 
e.g 17 .

i.e

```
if tb1.user_pic > 0 Then 
  choose their profile image
else 
   choose a default image.

SELECT tb1.user_id , tb1.full_names , tb1.user_email , tb1.user_pic , tb1.userName , 
tb2.img_id , tb2.img_format , tb2.img_by , tb2.img_album
FROM users as tb1
LEFT JOIN images as tb2
ON tb2.img_by = tb1.user_id
WHERE tb1.user_id = '$session_id' && tb2.img_id = tb1.user_pic
ORDER BY tb1.user_id
```

the above query will return no results  for users without prof pic which is the problem. I was thinking conditional statement might work but i have no idea how to use them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a possible alternative which will greatly simplify, and possibly speed up (though you should *measure* this as with all optimisation claims), your queries.

Consider assigning the default image to users when they join then simply allow them to override it. That way, every user has an image which can be extracted the exact same way regardless of whether they've configured one or not.

And, unless you're planning on millions and millions of users, the space requirements shouldn't be onerous.

You can still maintain a field in the table to state whether a real image has been chosen, even though that technically may violate 3NF. Most people don't realise but it's quite okay to do that sort of thing (usually for performance or simplification) provided you understand and/or mitigate the possible problems.

Comment: I was thinking the same but assigning every user a default will add  redundancy in the table since all default images are the same.

Comment: Yes, that was the whole point of the answer, to introduce redundancy in order to simplify the query. Few people complain about the space taken by their DB, most concerns are either speed or simplifying queries.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have decided to create an extra table for profile images so that every user has one row in that table for their prof pic which can be overridden(updated) when they either add , delete or change their prof pic. A default of zero is allocated for a user prof pic when they create an account, In this way the query i have will work for all users with or without prof pics.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-queries for all columns you want to retrieve from images. Don't use join there.

```
 SELECT tb1.user_id, tb1.full_names, tb1.user_email, tb1.user_pic, tb1.userName, 

        IsNull((select tb2.img_id from images tb2 where tb2.img_id = tb1.user_pic and tb2.img_by = tb1.user_id), 0) AS img_id, 

        IsNull((select tb2.img_format from images tb2 where tb2.img_id = tb1.user_pic and tb2.img_by = tb1.user_id), 'jpg') AS img_format,

        IsNull((select tb2.tb2.img_album from images tb2 where tb2.img_id = tb1.user_pic and tb2.img_by = tb1.user_id), 'default') AS img_album

 FROM users as tb1

 WHERE tb1.user_id = '$session_id'
 ORDER BY tb1.user_id
```

Although I am not sure about the existence of IsNull(,) or its syntax in MySQL. You may set a default image url for users with no profile pic.

Comment: This will work but i was avoiding using sub queries since speed of the query will be slower.